# Using xdebug with Netbeans for php - socket exception

Tags: php, macos, netbeans, xdebug

I'm trying to get php debugging working with xdebug using Netbeans but I'm getting a Socket Exception thrown in netbeans. It correctly stops at the breakpoint, but when I click to 'step over' or 'step into' or anything, it will display the socket exception and crash. Any help here would be much appreciated, I've spent a great deal of time trying to resolve this.

The environment I'm running is:

```
Mac OSX 10.7.4
Netbeans IDE 7.2
MAMP Version 2.1.1
php5.4.4
xdebug
```

From phpinfo:

```
This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2012 Zend Technologies
with XCache v2.0.0, Copyright (c) 2005-2012, by mOo
with Xdebug v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2012, by Derick Rethans
```

From php.ini:

```
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_log="/Applications/MAMP/logs/xdebug_remote.log"

zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.4/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/xdebug.so"
```

The output from my IDE Log when the exception occurs is as follows.

```
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.parsing.impl.TaskProcessor]: Task: class org.netbeans.modules.csl.hints.GsfHintsProvider ignored cancel for 266 ms.
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.URIMapper]: class org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.URIMapper$1: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/glog/index.php -> file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/glog/index.php
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.URIMapper]: class org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.URIMapper$1: /Users/Manachi/Work/myapp/index.php -> file:///Users/Manachi/Work/myapp/index.php
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.URIMapper]: class org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.URIMapper$1: /Users/Manachi/Work/adwaf/php/adwaf/portal/index.php -> file:///Users/Manachi/Work/adwaf/php/adwaf/portal/index.php
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.URIMapper]: class org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.URIMapper$1: file:///Users/Manachi/Work/adwaf/php/adwaf/portal/index.php -> /Users/Manachi/Work/adwaf/php/adwaf/portal/index.php
SEVERE [org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.packets.DbgpMessage]
SEVERE [org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.packets.DbgpMessage]
INFO [org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.DebugSession]
java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:124)
    at org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.packets.DbgpCommand.send(DbgpCommand.java:92)
    at org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.DebugSession.sendCommands(DebugSession.java:211)
[catch] at org.netbeans.modules.php.dbgp.DebugSession.run(DebugSession.java:143)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're running an old (and known broken) version of Xdebug. You want to use the latest (2.2.1 at the moment). And secondly, XCache is known to interfere with Xdebug as well, so you will want to disable that too.

Comment: This worked perfectly - thank you! I assumed because xdebug appeared to be loaded correctly in phpinfo() output that the version was ok. I have now made both the changes you suggested (2.2.1 AND disabling xcache) and it now works a charm. Thanks again.

Comment: i was using this solution http://intermarketing.merkados.com/install-xdebug-with-your-mamp-mac-os-x-10-6 and it was not working correctly. I installed by source the 2.2.1 version and it's ok now.